# Is the following code good practice for doing something with a recaptcha response?

Tags: node.js, express, recaptcha

I'm adding recaptcha to a form and would like to know if there are any foreseeable problems with the following code:

```
router.post("/recaptcha", function(req, res) {

  const secret = process.env.SECRET_KEY;
  const userResponse = req.body["g-recaptcha-response"];
  const url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secret + "&response=" + userResponse;

  https.get(url, function(response) {

    response.on("data", function(data) {
      const success = JSON.parse(data).success;

      if (success === true) {

        //  do something

      } else {

        //  do something else

      }
    });
  });
});
```

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Biggest issue I see: no apparent error handling

Comment: Great. Thanks for reply